# Python script to wait for bash prompt to appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pyautogui

I want to automate putty , i know there is paramiko and other ssh libraries available.
But i want to get logs as if i typed commands manually.
Is it possible to make python script wait till [user@server~]# appears then enter the command. 
I am using pyautogui...
I have tried searching pyautogui docs but could not find any .
Is there anything subprocess module can do . I am new to python sorry.
I have tried using image but it is not a good option.

```
import pyautogui
image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png")

 #Searches for the image
  while image == None:
     image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png")
     print("still haven't found the image")
```

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to pass an argument to ssh like `ssh -c command` does, or maybe just `scp remote local` to copy the logs to your local PC?